# Performance Effect of Methodization on JAVA

Tags: java, methods

Example Code without using Method:

```
if (exampleObject =! null && exampleObject.isTrusted() && exampleObject.isVerified() && objectMapNode.isObjectIncluded (exampleObject)){
    objectMapNode.add(exampleObject)
} else {
    return;
}
```

Example Code with using Method:

```
if (exampleObject =! null && !isCanSkipObject(exampleObject)){
    objectMapNode.add(exampleObject)
} else {
    return;
}

public boolean isCanSkipObject(Object obj) {
    return (exampleObject.isTrusted() && exampleObject.isVerified() && objectMapNode.isObjectIncluded (exampleObject));
}
```

I just want to ask, if methodization can causes delay or not. What do you prefer?

Is there a performance difference between complete an action directly or complete this action with calling method(argument) and return the result?

Answer (score 4):

I certainly prefer the example where you refactored part of the if condition to a method. Performance impact is negligible, if any. I trust the just in time compiler to make an optimal decision for me.

In general, I always go for readability first and only optimize later if it doesn't perfom.